# How to call another class in Jframe form class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, httpurlconnection

I have a Jframe form class like this

```
  public class LoginForm extends javax.swing.JFrame
```

In this,i get username & password from user and then send it to php server for validation and 
will get the response as OK or Invalid User. I have another class named '**public class LoginTimer      implements Runnable'** . In this class i have some code to execute. I want that in '**LoginForm**' when i   got response as OK, the control will move to second class '**LoginTimer**' means second class will be
 called. please tell me how to do it??
    =====================================================================

```
 private void sendGet(String username,String pwd) throws Exception
{
      String url = "http://localhost/login.php?username="+username+ "&password="+pwd;
      final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
      URL obj = new URL(url);
      HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
      con.setRequestMethod("GET");
      con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
      int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
      System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
      System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
      String inputLine;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
      {
        response.append(inputLine);
      }
      in.close();
     //print result
       String r=response.toString();
      System.out.println("String "+r);
      if(r.equals("OK"))
      {
          System.out.println("you are a valid user");

      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("You are an invalid user");
      }


 }
```

Below is my code for **LoginTimer** class. In this, I am getting names of visible windows and then thread starts and in **run()** method i call **sendGet()** method for sending window names to php server page. I want that when I got the OK response in **LoginForm** class,the **LoginTimer** class will be called and executed automatically.I mean, when user logged in & verified then sending of window names to php server will start automatically.

```
public class LoginTimer implements Runnable
{ 
 LoginTimer lk1;
 String s3;
 static int arraySize=10;
 static int arrayGrowth=2;
 static String[] m=new String[arraySize];
 static int count=0;

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      for(int ck=0;ck<3;ck++)
      {File file=new File("G:\\check.txt");
      Scanner scanner = null;
      try
      {
         scanner = new Scanner(file);
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
      {
         Logger.getLogger(LoginTimer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }

      while(scanner.hasNext())
      {
       String[] tokens = scanner.nextLine().split(":");
       String last = tokens[1];
      // System.out.println(last);
        if(last!=null)
        {
           try 
           {
              lk1.sendGet(last,m);

           }
           catch (Exception ex) 
           {
              Logger.getLogger(LoginTimer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
        }
      } 
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginTimer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
      }

   }

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    (new Thread(new LoginTimer())).start();
    final List<WindowInfo> inflList=new ArrayList<WindowInfo>();
    final List<Integer> order=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int top = User32.instance.GetTopWindow(0);
    while (top!=0)
    {
      order.add(top);
      top = User32.instance.GetWindow(top, User32.GW_HWNDNEXT);
    }
    User32.instance.EnumWindows(new WndEnumProc()
    {
     public boolean callback(int hWnd, int lParam)
     { 
      if (User32.instance.IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) 
      {
        RECT r = new RECT();
        User32.instance.GetWindowRect(hWnd, r);
        if (r.left>-32000) 
        {     // minimized
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
           User32.instance.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, buffer, buffer.length);
           String title = Native.toString(buffer);
           //lk1.getid(title);
           if (m.length == count)
        {
              // expand list
             m = Arrays.copyOf(m, m.length + arrayGrowth);
            }
            m[count]=Native.toString(buffer);
            System.out.println("title===="+m[count]);
            count++;

            inflList.add(new WindowInfo(hWnd, r, title));
        }

       }
       return true;
    }
    }, 0);

 Collections.sort(inflList, new Comparator<WindowInfo>()
 {
    public int compare(WindowInfo o1, WindowInfo o2)
    {
    return order.indexOf(o1.hwnd)-order.indexOf(o2.hwnd);
    }
 });
  for (WindowInfo w : inflList)
  {
     System.out.println(w);
  }


}


 public static interface WndEnumProc extends StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback
 {
     boolean callback (int hWnd, int lParam);
 }

 public static interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary
 {
    final User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary ("user32", User32.class);
    boolean EnumWindows (WndEnumProc wndenumproc, int lParam);
    boolean IsWindowVisible(int hWnd);
    int GetWindowRect(int hWnd, RECT r);
    void GetWindowTextA(int hWnd, byte[] buffer, int buflen);
    int GetTopWindow(int hWnd);
    int GetWindow(int hWnd, int flag);
    final int GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;

 }
 public static class RECT extends Structure 
 {
    public int left,top,right,bottom;
 }
 public static class WindowInfo 
 {
    int hwnd;
    RECT rect;
    String title;
    public WindowInfo(int hwnd, RECT rect, String title)
    {
        this.hwnd = hwnd; this.rect = rect; this.title = title;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
     return String.format("(%d,%d)-(%d,%d) : \"%s\"",
     rect.left ,rect.top,rect.right,rect.bottom,title);
    }
  }

 public static void sendGet(String last1,String[] get) throws Exception 
 {       

    for(int t=0;t<get.length;t++)
    {
      if(get[t]!=null)
      {
      String url = "http://localhost/add_windows.php?username="+last1+"&windowname="+get[t];
      final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
      URL obj = new URL(url);
  HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
  con.setRequestMethod("GET");
      con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
      int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
      System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
  System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
  String inputLine;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
      {
    response.append(inputLine);
  }
  in.close();
      String r=response.toString();
      System.out.println("String "+r);
      }
     }


 }

}
```

Comment: Add all the code you're mentioning about. For example you haven't given us the code for the LoginTimer and where you use it

Comment: @Can'tTell I have edited my code. Have a look on LoginTimer class code

Comment: How do you know that the LoginTimer's run method is not executing? Add a System.out.println at the top of the run method and see if that gets printed. Or use a debugger and debug the run method. It can be that the run method is throwing an exception and that's why you can't see its output.

Comment: When I wrote lt.start() in LoginForm, it gives warning that it should be implemented in LoginTimer.I did that.but block of Start() in LoginTimer is blank.I am new to Threads,please tell me how to start that thread from implemented Start() method

Comment: I added System.out.println at start of run method and also at end of run method.both are executing.Butin between code is not executing.I mean calling of sendGet method.

Comment: If the lines are getting printed and your logic is not running, most probably an exception is being thrown in the in between code.

Comment: How to avoid that exception and get my code executed???

Comment: I said it is possible that an exception is being thrown. I'm not sure. Are you using an IDE like [eclipse](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliosm6) for your development? Then you can use [debugging](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) to find out the problem in your code.

Comment: I found the problem,run method is executing, but main() method is not executing. Thats why it is not fetching window names.

Comment: I solved it. Thanks. I called the main method from LoginForm class and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your class implements java.lang.Runnable.

To have the run() method executed by a thread, pass an instance of your class_implementing_Runnable to a Thread in its constructor.Something like

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new LoginTimer());
   thread.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

As u are implementing runnable class you are creating thread. So create an object of `LoginTimer` as 
        `LoginTimer lt = new LoginTimer();`
    in `LoginForm class` after you get result from php page.

Now call

```
   lt.start();
```

after ur creation of object ; which will call ur run method of thread.

Now in ur `LoginTimer class` override the run method like

```
   class LoginTimer implements Runnable
   {
   public void run()
   {
   //put your code which you want to execute now ... 
   }
   }
```

Comment: I did it. not working.means when i got OK response,i start thread,but still the code in second class in not executing

Comment: @JavaFresher How do you know it's not executing? Did you debug the code or is it in some other way?c Can you post your login timer code as well?

Comment: @Can'tTell I mean on getting a valid response, i start thread in LoginForm. So it should also show output of LoginTimer class.But it is not showing anything.

Comment: I want my main method to be executed first and then run method will be execute